# "Bitte schön" als Antwort auf "Danke". Eigentlich gar nicht freundlich?

Tags: etymology

Auf "Danke sehr" gilt es als freundlich mit "Bitte schön" zu antworten.

Warum soll ich nach einem Dank eine Bitte anfordern? Das ist ja viel eher arrogant als freundlich. Oder woher kommt das?

Comment: Schon mal selber nachgeforscht? Oder ist das jetzt eher arrogant als freundlich nachgefragt?

Comment: Entsprechende Frage auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/why-bittesch%c3%b6n

Comment: @Herr Derb Wer sagt denn dass 'bitte schön' eine Bitte anfordert?

Comment: @Berend: Jmd., der das *bitte* imperativ versteht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DWDS zitiert](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bitte) zur Wortherkunft von "bitte" als höfliche Antwort auf "danke":

> Die adverbial gebrauchte Höflichkeitsformel *bitte* ist eine im 18. Jh. aufkommende (in gesprochener Sprache wohl ältere) Verkürzung aus ich bitte.

Gemeint ist also ursprünglich, dass man darum bittet, gar nicht zu danken bzw. das Danken zu unterlassen. Es ist also eigentlich sogar übetrieben freundlich.

In längerer Form ist das ja auch noch immer noch eine übliche Formel:

> "Ich danke Ihnen sehr für Ihre Hilfe!" -- "Aber ich bitte Sie, das ist doch nicht der Rede wert."

Das norddeutsche "Dafür nicht!" (oder "Da nicht für!") geht in die gleiche Richtung.

Das aktuell populär werdende "Gerne!" dagegen bedeutet ja erst einmal, dass man den Dank durchaus annimmt, ist also im ursprünglichen Sinn sogar eine Stufe weniger höflich als "Bitte".

Comment: Ich würde das "Gerne" eher im Sinne von "Gern geschehen" verstehen.

Comment: @Bodo: so verstehe ich es auch. Bedeutet "gern geschehen" für dich nicht, dass man den Dank annimmt?

Comment: Ich verstehe das nicht als Aussage darüber ob man den Dank annimmt, sondern nur, daß man das gern gemacht hat und deshalb keinen Dank erwartet.

Comment: Wieso ist es weniger höflich, Dank anzunehmen, als Dank zurückzuweisen? Ich finde im Gegenteil die Zurückweisung von Dank eher als unhöfliich.